FPGA VGA signal is not supported by monitor
I'm working on a FPGA project and I'm trying to get a VGA output to my monitor. The problem I'm facing is that the monitor tells me the input signal is not supported, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
FPGA Code:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity VGA_Controller is
    Port (
        clk        : in  STD_LOGIC;      -- 25MHz klok
        h_sync     : out STD_LOGIC;      -- Horizontale synchronisatie
        v_sync     : out STD_LOGIC;      -- Verticale synchronisatie
        vgaRed     : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0); -- Red signal (4 bits)
        vgaGreen   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0); -- Green signal (4 bits)
        vgaBlue    : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0)  -- Blue signal (4 bits)
    );
end VGA_Controller;

architecture Behavioral of VGA_Controller is
    -- VGA-timings voor 640x480 @ 60Hz
    constant h_pixels : integer := 640;  -- Aantal pixels per lijn
    constant h_fp     : integer := 16;   -- Front porch
    constant h_sync_p : integer := 96;   -- Sync pulse
    constant h_bp     : integer := 48;   -- Back porch
    constant h_total  : integer := 800;  -- Totale pixels (640 + porches)

    constant v_pixels : integer := 480;  -- Aantal lijnen per frame
    constant v_fp     : integer := 10;   -- Front porch
    constant v_sync_p : integer := 2;    -- Sync pulse
    constant v_bp     : integer := 33;   -- Back porch
    constant v_total  : integer := 525;  -- Totale lijnen (480 + porches)

    signal h_count : integer := 0;
    signal v_count : integer := 0;

begin
    process(clk)
    begin
         if rising_edge(clk) then
            -- Horizontale teller
            if h_count = h_total - 1 then
                h_count <= 0;
                -- Verticale teller
                if v_count = v_total - 1 then
                    v_count <= 0;
                else
                    v_count <= v_count + 1;
                end if;
            else
                h_count <= h_count + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- Synchronisatiesignalen genereren
    h_sync <= '0' when (h_count >= h_pixels + h_fp and h_count < h_pixels + h_fp + 
h_sync_p) else '1';
    v_sync <= '0' when (v_count >= v_pixels + v_fp and v_count < v_pixels + v_fp + 
v_sync_p) else '1';

    -- RGB-signalen genereren (bijv. blauw scherm)
    vgaRed   <= "0000"; -- No red
    vgaGreen <= "0000"; -- No green
    vgaBlue  <= "1111" when (h_count < h_pixels and v_count < v_pixels) else "0000"; -- 
Full blue when within visible area
end Behavioral;

Constrains File:
set_property PACKAGE_PIN <pin_name> [get_ports {clk}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {clk}]
create_clock -period 40 [get_pins {clk}]  # 25 MHz = 40 ns period

## VGA Connector
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G19 [get_ports {vgaRed[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaRed[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H19 [get_ports {vgaRed[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaRed[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J19 [get_ports {vgaRed[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaRed[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN N19 [get_ports {vgaRed[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaRed[3]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN J17 [get_ports {vgaGreen[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaGreen[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN H17 [get_ports {vgaGreen[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaGreen[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G17 [get_ports {vgaGreen[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaGreen[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN D17 [get_ports {vgaGreen[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaGreen[3]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN N18 [get_ports {vgaBlue[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaBlue[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN L18 [get_ports {vgaBlue[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaBlue[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN K18 [get_ports {vgaBlue[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaBlue[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN J18 [get_ports {vgaBlue[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {vgaBlue[3]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN P19 [get_ports Hsync]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports Hsync]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN R19 [get_ports Vsync]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports Vsync]


What monitor are you using? A lot of modern monitors no longer support 640x480 resolution - it's simply too low frequency for them to handle. Try connecting the monitor to a PC or Laptop and selecting that resolution to see if it works.

The VGA 640x480 @ 60 Hz standard requires a 25.175 MHz pixel clock, but your FPGA design uses 25 MHz. While close, some monitors are strict about timing and might reject the slightly off frequency.

have you, by the way, verified that analog-wise, a somewhat sensible VGA signal comes out of your (often lengthy!) VGA cable, for example by looking at it with an oscilloscope?

To expand on the timing point made above, you can try adjusting v_total to 521 and v_fp to 6 to correct the vertical frequency. OR you can try adjusting h_total to 794 and h_fp to 10 to correct the horizontal and vertical frequencies.  What hardware are you using?

@TomCarpenter If a monitor has VGA connector, the assumption is it supports 640x480@60Hz. Even DVI and HDMI require mandatory support of same resolution. Thus I highly doubt modern displays will refuse to show it, but feel free to point me at a manual which says it is not supported.

@SteKulov It is better to adjust the H frequency if something is to be adjusted. The amount of lines per frame should stay constant for best results.

@Justme You'd think, but alas. We teach an FPGA module using a VGA connector at the Uni I work out - all the screens in our teaching labs were updated this year, and it's killed all our VGA demos - the screens (some modern iiyama model) simply refuse to display low res like 640x480. Previous years we had some screens work and not others (the non-working ones were one model, the working ones a different model). Happy to ammend my statement to "some" rather than "a lot of"

@Justme Completely agree. I only mentioned the former since that’s how they did it in an FPGA lab book I used 13 years ago. Haha.

@TomCarpenter I looked up a random Iiyama monitor at the local store, the T1931SAW-B5. The provided data states f_HOR = 31..80 kHz and f_VER = 50..75 Hz. This matches perfectly the frequencies of the standard VGA 640x480, which uses 31.4688 kHz and 59,94 Hz, respectively.

@liaifat85 I changed the clock speed and now I'm able to see the different colors, thanks a lot to everyone that helped me on this one :)
